# I'm getting "Error Reading File" in a script, what am I missing?

Tags: python, scrape

I'm running a scraping script on python 2.7 OS X to scrape products from Aliexpress ,but when running the script I get the following error message from terminal. PS The product links were listed on a .txt file.

```
Last login: Wed Jun  7 16:24:05 on ttys001
RSs-MacBook-Air:~ MyMacbookAir$ cd desktop
RSs-MacBook-Air:desktop MyMacbookAir$ python aliexpresscrape.py
Path to File: /Users/MyMacbookAir/Desktop/fileurls.txt     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aliexpresscrape.py", line 70, in <module>
    read(selection)
  File "aliexpresscrape.py", line 69, in read
    scrape(str(lines[j]))
  File "aliexpresscrape.py", line 18, in scrape
    title2 = str(lxml.html.parse(url).find(".//title").text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 940, in parse
    return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3442, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:81716)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1811, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:118635)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1837, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:118982)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1741, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:117894)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1138, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:112440)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 595, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105896)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 706, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:107604)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 633, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106415)
IOError: Error reading file 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/AFOFOO-Gothic-Steampunk-Mens-Sunglasses-Vintage-Metal-Men-Coating-Mirror-Sunglasses-Male-Round-Sun-glasses-Retro/32784155756.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.43.M90zfm&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10065_10151_10130_10068_5010014_10136_10137_10060_10138_10155_10062_437_10154_10056_10055_10054_10059_303_100031_10099_10103_10102_10096_10052_10053_10107_10050_10142_10051_5030014_9946_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10178_10110_519_9168_10111_10112_10113_10114_10182_10078_10079_10073_10123_10189_142-9946_9168,searchweb201603_1,ppcSwitch_5&btsid=fd7dbd9c-11fc-4795-8476-6fb77990127e&algo_expid=41aa2ba2-d7ea-4bf8-ab59-4956f5759e05-6&algo_pvid=41aa2ba2-d7ea-4bf8-ab59-4956f5759e05': failed to load external entity "https://www.aliexpress.com/item/AFOFOO-Gothic-Steampunk-Mens-Sunglasses-Vintage-Metal-Men-Coating-Mirror-Sunglasses-Male-Round-Sun-glasses-Retro/32784155756.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.43.M90zfm&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10065_10151_10130_10068_5010014_10136_10137_10060_10138_10155_10062_437_10154_10056_10055_10054_10059_303_100031_10099_10103_10102_10096_10052_10053_10107_10050_10142_10051_5030014_9946_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10178_10110_519_9168_10111_10112_10113_10114_10182_10078_10079_10073_10123_10189_142-9946_9168,searchweb201603_1,ppcSwitch_5&btsid=fd7dbd9c-11fc-4795-8476-6fb77990127e&algo_expid=41aa2ba2-d7ea-4bf8-ab59-4956f5759e05-6&algo_pvid=41aa2ba2-d7ea-4bf8-ab59-4956f5759e05"
RSs-MacBook-Air:desktop MyMacbookAir$ python aliexpresscrape.py
Path to File: /Users/MyMacbookAir/Desktop/fileurls.txt 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aliexpresscrape.py", line 70, in <module>
    read(selection)
  File "aliexpresscrape.py", line 69, in read
    scrape(str(lines[j]))
  File "aliexpresscrape.py", line 18, in scrape
    title2 = str(lxml.html.parse(url).find(".//title").text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 940, in parse
    return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3442, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:81716)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1811, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:118635)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1837, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:118982)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1741, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:117894)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1138, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:112440)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 595, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105896)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 706, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:107604)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 633, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106415)
IOError: Error reading file 'https://www.aliexpress.com/category/100003088/shorts.html?spm=2114.20010208.8.79.lz5vt4&site=glo&g=y&pvId=10-100019017&attrRel=or&tc=af': failed to load external entity "https://www.aliexpress.com/category/100003088/shorts.html?spm=2114.20010208.8.79.lz5vt4&site=glo&g=y&pvId=10-100019017&attrRel=or&tc=af"
RSs-MacBook-Air:desktop MyMacbookAir$
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
from lxml import html
import lxml.html
import requests
import csv
from csv import writer
#variables
selection = raw_input("Path to File: ")
csv_header = ("post_title","post_name","ID","post_excerpt","post_content","post_status","menu_order","post_date","post_parent","post_author","comment_status","sku","downloadable","virtual","visibility","stock","stock_status","backorders","manage_stock","regular_price","sale_price","weight","length","width","height","tax_status","tax_class","upsell_ids","crosssell_ids","featured","sale_price_dates_from","sale_price_dates_to","download_limit","download_expiry","product_url","button_text","meta:_yoast_wpseo_focuskw","meta:_yoast_wpseo_title","meta:_yoast_wpseo_metadesc","meta:_yoast_wpseo_metakeywords","images","downloadable_files","tax:product_type","tax:product_cat","tax:product_tag","tax:product_shipping_class","meta:total_sales","attribute:pa_color","attribute_data:pa_color","attribute_default:pa_color","attribute:size","attribute_data:size","attribute_default:size")

#write header to output file (runs once)
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer=csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(csv_header)

def scrape(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    title2 = str(lxml.html.parse(url).find(".//title").text)
    title2 = title2.replace('-' + title2.split("-", 1)[1], '')
    price = tree.xpath("//span[@itemprop='price']//text()")
    i = 0
    for span in tree.cssselect('span'):
        clas = span.get('class')
        rel = span.get('rel')
        if clas == "packaging-des":
            if rel != None:
                if i == 0:
                    weight = rel
                elif i == 1:
                    dim = str(rel)
                i = i+1

    weight = weight
    height = dim.split("|", 3)[0]
    length = dim.split("|", 3)[1]
    width = dim.split("|", 3)[2]
    #Sometimes aliexpress doesn't list a price
    #This dumps a 0 into price in that case to stop the errors
    if len(price) == 1:
        price = float(str(price[0]))
    elif len(price) == 0:
        price = int(0)
    for inpu in tree.cssselect('input'):
        if inpu.get("id") == "hid-product-id":
            sku = inpu.get('value')
    for meta in tree.cssselect('meta'):
        name = meta.get("name")
        prop = meta.get("property")
        content = meta.get('content')
        if prop == 'og:image':
            image = meta.get('content')
        if name == 'keywords':
             keywords = meta.get('content')
        if name == 'description':
            desc = meta.get('content')
    listvar = ([str(title2),str(name), '', '', str(desc), 'publish', '', '', '0', '1', 'open', str(sku), 'no', 'no', 'visible', '', 'instock', 'no', 'no', str(price*2),str(price*1.5), str(weight), str(length), str(width), str(height), 'taxable', '', '', '', 'no', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', str(keywords), str(image), '', 'simple', '', '', '', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''])
    with open("output.csv",'ab') as f:
        writer=csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(listvar)

def read(selection):
    lines = []
    j = 0
    with open(selection) as f:
        for line in f:
            lines.append(line)
        lines = map(lambda s: s.strip(), lines)    
    for j in range(len(lines)):
        scrape(str(lines[j]))
read(selection)
```

Comment: Sorry, but my crystal ball is at the shop - could you please post the code that is generating the error?

Comment: Please let us see the code, then we can help

Comment: Maybe the website you're scaping has a rate limiter and it's blocking you.

Comment: @Stiffy2000 Just went ahead and updated my question with the original code.

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig please see updated code. Thanks

Comment: @ron9091 change `lxml.html.parse(url)` to `lxml.html.parse(page.content)`

Comment: @jordanm hi, tried that and I'm still getting an error.